# Using an RGB TFT screen on the Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, display, rgb, tft

I want to use the HT0700EI02A TFT screen on the Raspberry Pi 4 Compute Module.

- Raspberry Datasheet: https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/cm4/cm4-datasheet.pdf
  [image: CM4 Alternatives Functions]
- Screen Datasheet: https://cdn.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/623388_201461.pdf
  [image: Screen pins]

Apparently, this screen uses a protocol called 24-bit RGB. But in addition to HDMI, raspberri only has the DPI (Parallel RGB Display) interface.

The screen's datasheet informs you that 8 data inputs are used for each RGB color, totaling 24 pins. The raspberry datasheet states that the DPI interface uses 24 data pins. LCD_VSYNC,LCD_HSYNC, DE, DCLK pins are shown in both datasheets. So far, it seems to be the same protocol.

However, some pins on the screen do not match with raspberry, such as L/R(39), U/D(40).

My question is: are they the same protocol? How do I turn on the display on my raspberry?

I didn't find much information about the protocol and its use on the Raspberry Pi. If anyone can give me a tip to start the work, I appreciate it.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the same protocol.

And, you turn on the display by providing all the necessary power supplies, such as for the panel and backlight. The TFT panel manual must have instructions how to power it and reset it properly to show a picture, or it may refer to the display driver IC data.

L/R and U/D are not part of the pixel transmission protocol, as they control the horizontal and vertical flip of the display. There is no need for the RPi to drive those, that is pixel data.

Now, the next problem is, you need to figure out which RPi data pins are red, green and blue bits, so that you know in which order to connect them to the display.